# Elasticsearch array must and must_not

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering

I have a documents looking like this in my elasticsearch DB :

```
{
   "tags"   =>   [
      "tag-1",
      "tag-2",
      "tag-3",
      "tag-A"
   ]
   "created_at"   =>"2013-07-02 12:42:19   UTC",
   "label"   =>"Mon super label"
}
```

I would like to be able to filter my documents with this criteria :
Documents tags array must have tags-1, tags-3 and tags-2 but must not have tags-A.

I tried to use a bool  filter but I can't manage to make it work !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a method that seems to accomplish you want: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4dd806936f12a9668d61ce63f39cb2c284512443

First I created an index with an explicit mapping. I did this so I could set the `"tags"` property to `"index": "not_analyzed"`. This means that the text will not be modified in any way, which will simplify the querying process for this example.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index" -d'
{
    "mappings": {
        "docs" : {
            "properties": {
                "tags" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "label" : {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

and then add some docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/1" -d'
{
    "tags" : [
        "tag-1",
        "tag-2",
        "tag-3",
        "tag-A"
    ],
    "label" : "item 1"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/2" -d'
{
    "tags" : [
        "tag-1",
        "tag-2",
        "tag-3"
    ],
    "label" : "item 2"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/3" -d'
{
    "tags" : [
        "tag-1",
        "tag-2"
    ],
    "label" : "item 3"
}'
```

Then we can query using `must` and `must_not` clauses in a `bool` filter as follows:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "tags": [
                           "tag-1",
                           "tag-2",
                           "tag-3"
                        ],
                        "execution" : "and"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "must_not": [
                  {
                      "term": {
                         "tags": "tag-A"
                      }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

which yields the correct result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "tags": [
                  "tag-1",
                  "tag-2",
                  "tag-3"
               ],
               "label": "item 2"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Notice the `"execution" : "and"` parameter in the `terms` filter in the `must` clause. This means only docs that have all the `"tags"` specified will be returned (rather than those that match one or more). That may have been what you were missing. You can read more about the options in the [ES docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html).

I made a runnable example [here](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4dd806936f12a9668d61ce63f39cb2c284512443) that you can play with, if you have ES installed and running at `localhost:9200`, or you can provide your own endpoint.