# Term, nested documents and must_not query incompatible in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have trouble combining term, must_not queries on nested documents.

Sense example can be found here : http://sense.qbox.io/gist/be436a1ffa01e4630a964f48b2d5b3a1ef5fa176

Here my mapping :

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "docs" : {
            "properties": {
                "tags" : {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "type": {
                           "type": "string",
                           "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "label" : {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with two documents in this index :

```
{
    "tags" : [
        {"type" : "POST"},
        {"type" : "DELETE"}
    ],
    "label" : "item 1"
},
{
    "tags" : [
        {"type" : "POST"}
    ],
    "label" : "item 2"
}
```

When I query this index like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "tags.type": "DELETE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I've got one hit (which is correct)**

When I want to get documents WHICH DON'T CONTAIN the tag "DELETE", with this query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "tags.type": "delete"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I've got 2 hits (which is incorrect).**
This issue seems very close to this one ([Elasticsearch array must and must_not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168375/elasticsearch-array-must-and-must-not)) but it's not...

Can you give me some clues to resolve this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem:  http://sense.qbox.io/gist/f4694f542bc76c29624b5b5c9b3ecdee36f7e3ea

Two most important things:

1. include_in_root on "tags.type".  This will tell ES to index tag types as `"doc.tags.types" : ['DELETE', 'POSTS']`, so you can access an array of those values "flattened" on the root doc . This means you no longer need a nested query (see #2)
2. Drop the nested query.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "docs" : {
            "properties": {
                "tags" : {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "type": {
                           "type": "string",
                           "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    },
                    "include_in_root": true
                },
                "label" : {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": {
            "term": {
               "tags.type": "DELETE"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain why you did that way ?

Comment: Simply because it was not possible without "include_in_root".  Instead of having a complex nested filter/query system, you can now just treat all "tags.type" as an array.  That way, you can say something like "give me all the docs without 'DELETE' in the tag types array".

It's not easy to verbalize this stuff sometimes, but hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. That's both weird and sad. Does it maybe because I use `terms` and `integer`?

Comment: You can also do `"include_in_parent": true`

Answer (score 24):

Your original query would search in each individual nested object and eliminate the objects that don't match, but if there are some nested objects left, they do match with your query and so you get your results. This is because nested objects are ***indexed as a hidden separate document***

Original code:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "tags.type": "delete"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The solution is then quite simple really, you should bring the bool query outside the nested documents. Now all the documents are discarded who have a nested object with the "**DELETE**" type. Just what you wanted!

The solution:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags",
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "tags.type": "DELETE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: Your strings are "not analyzed" and you searched for "delete" instead of "DELETE". If you want to search case insensitive, make your strings analyzed

Comment: If I do it this way, data which has no tags field is not included to the result

Comment: Are you sure about that? Which Elasticsearch version do you use?

Comment: ElasticSearch 2.2.1. After rechecking, a lot of query works fine in my laptop, but in the server. The Elasticsearch version may play a role.

Comment: I think you mean _not_ in the server. Which ES version do you use there? And did _ALL_ the queries work on the laptop? If they did, I think my solution still stands. In fact, I use this solution everyday in production...

Comment: It doesn't work on the server, and the server uses version 2.2.1 like I told in the previous comment. I haven't tried it on my own laptop

Comment: Did you test the latest changes?